# How do I get NON-tradeable assets via the Coinbase PRO API for use in google sheets?

Tags: api, google-sheets, coinbase-api

I am using this formula in google sheets to pull the current price of tradeable assets on coinbase.

=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker"),0,2), "price:",""), """", ""))

Super simple and works great. I can change "ETH" in the URL to the ticker of any tradeable asset, i.e., "BTC" and it returns the price of that asset.

However, when I change to a NON trade-able asset, for example SAMO, I get an error.

Is there a similar URL structure I can use to get SAMO, for example?

Comment: you can't.  The exchange api doesn't contain non-coinbase assets.

Answer (score 0):

> via the Coinbase PRO API

The short answer is "you can't" because coinbase doesn't track those coins.

An easy way to see every available traded pair would be to run the [products api](https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products)

To see it formatted nicely you can do to the docs and run it [here, just click "try it"](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getproducts).